# Nodejs Deployment on VPS, WHM

Tags: node.js, deployment, cpanel, vps, whm

Hello I have Apis written in nodejs. I want to deploy them on my cPanel. I have Hosting VPS hosting. in my software section I can't see Nodejs Applications. there is only PHPManager.

Please guide

Answer (score 0):

The only answer is hostagor don't provide node.js application manager to its c panel if we are on vps we have to install nodejs with who terminal and deploy through application manager.